# Should i pass a Singleton as a function parameter

Tags: java, function, design-patterns, parameters, singleton

I recently encountered in a code review i was doing to a colleague, in a peculiar pattern i haven't seen before. He was sending a singleton as a parameter in a function and saved it in the calling class as a member.
Let's say i have a simple singleton class `Foo`

```
public class Foo {

private static Foo instance;
private int counter;

private Foo(){}

public static Foo getInstance(){
    if (instance == null){
        instance = new Foo();
    }
    return instance;
}

public int getCounter() {
    return counter;
}

public void setCounter(int counter) {
    this.counter = counter;
}
}
```

Now there's a client of `Foo` called `Bar`:

```
public class Bar {

private Foo foo;

public Bar(Foo foo){
    this.foo = foo;
    this.foo.setCounter(10);
    this.foo.setCounter(20);
}

public int getCounter(){
    return foo.getCounter();
}
}
```

So `Bar` does 2 unusual things - 1. Call `Foo` in the constructor, instead of just using `Foo.getInstance()` and 2. Save `Foo` as a member so to 'save' the boilerplate of calling `Foo.getInstance()` it uses it. Of course the usages i demonstrated are trivial.

This looked odd and awkward to me, and worse, i can't identify `Foo` as a singleton at all in `Bar` scope. What if i change something crucial in it's state? But other than that reason of code-readability, i couldn't say that it's not optional to do so, and the usage seems eventually valid. Was i right or wrong? and for what reason? is it right to pass this singleton and save it as a member?

Comment: None of the code you show creates an instance of Foo, since there is no call to Foo.getInstance(). .

Comment: 1. Isolation is good, it's ok if you can't tell `Foo` is a singleton.  2.  However singletons are an iffy design pattern and often abused  3.  Passing in `Foo` instead of calling `getInstance` is fine.  4.  Calling non-final methods in a ctor can be a fraught pattern, and might require attention.  Overall, without the documentation or the logic behind the design, it's hard to say one way or the other what is good or bad here.

Comment: This might be a better fit for Code Review, but your example is a little too simple I think to be able to give a good review.  I think the devil is going to  be in the details here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems like it's really subjective.  Keeping a reference to the singleton can handy if you think there is any possibility that the code may at some point not be a singleton anymore, or if you think you might move to a framework like Spring with dependency injection.  So you could say this is looking forward to future flexibility.  In general, singletons are frowned upon as being contrary to truly object-oriented code.

But at the same time, if your application relies heavily on singletons and this is a very typical pattern ... and if you're worried that somehow you might end up with duplicate instances of the singleton class because of this usage, then it's fine to argue that this code does not match your application's common pattern and usage expectation and it should follow expected guidelines.

Without knowing more about your application, team, etc., it's hard to give a more specific answer than that.

Answer (score 2):

Not conventional but I think that according to the usage :
1) Passing a singleton as a parameter to the constructor of another class may be valid. 
2) storing the singleton instance from a client of that may also be valid.
IOC can do that for example.

Now it may be undesirable if you want to add to `getInstance()` some logic : caching instances, returning different instances according to the timeline, the client and so for... But is really a good way to implement a singleton with so much logical ? Not sure...

> This looked odd and awkward to me, and worse, i can't identify Foo as
>   a singleton at all in Bar scope.

But the singleton pattern is also awkward. If the singleton pattern exposes the reference of the singleton instance to clients, these should be free to use it.

Why do you think that when you look at the Bar code you should be aware that Foo is a singleton ?
Bar depends on Foo because it needs that. The implementation (singleton or no) should not matter at its level.

In a general way the "hardcoded" singleton pattern should be avoided : a kind of global variable, harder to switch to other implementations, harder to mock...
If you could use the Java 5 enum that should not be hard to implement with your actual code it would be really better.

Additional note for the actual singleton :

It is not thread safe. Using the Bill Pugh idiom will do that easily.

```
public class Foo {

    private static class Holder{
       private static Foo instance = new Foo();
    }

    private Foo(){}

    public static Foo getInstance(){
        return Holder.instance();
    }
}
```

That is lazy instantiated as in your original code.
But in a general way it is much care to spare an instantiation that is not expensive and is bound to be required.
The eager way is so often preferred :

```
public class Foo {

    private static Foo instance = new Foo();

    private Foo(){}

    public static Foo getInstance(){
        return instance;
    }
}
```